How can I view an image in ranger without closing ranger?
I installed ranger console file manager on Ubuntu. I'd like to view images with it in the console (which I access via JupyterLab), so I also installed caca-utils, which contains img2txt:
sudo apt-get install ranger caca-utils

I launched ranger, selected a file, opened it with img2txt:

However, the image doesn't appear until I close ranger:

How can I view an image in ranger without closing ranger?

Possibly... open_with img2txt &  If not, make a script that you can "open_with" that will handle it.  Also, maybe try nnn instead of ranger.

@JayCravens thanks, with open_with img2txt &, the image doesn't appear until I close ranger. nnn  doesn't open images by default it seems.

Install w3m-img if it's not already.  Then open ranger, go to the image and press z then i.  It's showing in rangers preview, now.  Press ~ to open it.

@JayCravens thanks, sounds promising but I got a list index out of range error at the last step: https://i.sstatic.net/BH92S9oz.png Any idea why?

I found a setting called one_indexed...  it's set to false.  Maybe try :set one_indexed=True  Not sure, but looks like it's worth trying.
